# Implementing Mouse Magnet Effect in HTML Canvas Animation

Tags: html

I have recently converted a Pygame animation into HTML canvas using JavaScript with the help of ChatGPT. The animation consists of dynamic lines that move around the canvas, and I'd like to implement a mouse magnet effect similar to what was present in the original Pygame code.

Here's the JavaScript code for the HTML canvas animation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Background</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        canvas {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black; /* Set the canvas background color */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('backgroundCanvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        let lines = [];
        const width = canvas.width;
        const height = canvas.height;

        function update() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            if (Math.random() < 0.07) {
                lines.push({
                    x: Math.random() * width,
                    y: Math.random() * height,
                    fadeOut: false,
                    angle: Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI,
                    timer: 1,
                    rotationSpeed: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.02
                });
            }
            let temp = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                const line = lines[i];
                line.angle += line.rotationSpeed;
                if (line.angle > 2 * Math.PI) {
                    line.angle -= 2 * Math.PI;
                }
                if (line.timer === 0) {
                    lines.splice(i, 1);
                    continue;
                }
                const alpha = Math.min(120, line.timer);
                const endX = line.x + Math.floor(line.timer / 5 * Math.cos(line.angle));
                const endY = line.y + Math.floor(line.timer / 5 * Math.sin(line.angle));
                ctx.strokeStyle = `rgba(${alpha},${alpha},${alpha},1)`;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(line.x, line.y);
                ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
                ctx.stroke();
                line.x += Math.cos(line.angle);
                line.y += Math.sin(line.angle);
                if (line.x < 0 || line.x > width || line.y < 0 || line.y > height) {
                    lines.splice(i, 1);
                    continue;
                }
                if (line.timer > 500) {
                    line.fadeOut = true;
                }
                if (line.fadeOut) {
                    line.timer -= 1;
                } else {
                    line.timer += 1;
                }
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }
        update();

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking to add a mouse magnet effect where, when the mouse cursor is within a certain distance from a line, the line moves towards the mouse cursor. This effect was present in the original Pygame code, but I'm not sure how to implement it in the HTML canvas animation.

```
from pygame import init, QUIT
from pygame.draw import line as l, circle
from pygame.time import Clock
from pygame.display import set_mode, flip
from pygame.event import get
from pygame.mouse import get_pos
from random import randint, random, uniform
from math import sin, cos, dist, atan2, pi
from os import _exit
init()
lines = []
width = 1500
height = 700
screen = set_mode((width, height))
clock = Clock()
while True:
    for event in get(QUIT):
        _exit(0)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if random() < 0.07:
        lines.append({'x': randint(0, width),'y': randint(0, height), 'fade-out': False, 'angle': uniform(0, 2 * pi), 'timer': 1, 'rotation_speed': uniform(-0.01, 0.01)})
    temp = 0
    for line in lines:
        line['angle'] += line['rotation_speed']
        if line['angle'] > 2 * pi:
            line['angle'] -= 2 * pi
        if line['timer'] == 0:
            lines.remove(line)
            continue
        alpha = min([120, line['timer']])
        end_x = line['x'] + line['timer'] // 5 * cos(line['angle'])
        end_y = line['y'] + line['timer'] // 5 * sin(line['angle'])
        l(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (line['x'], line['y']), (end_x, end_y), 1)
        for other_line in lines:
            if line != other_line:
                x1 = line['x'] + line['timer'] // 5 * cos(line['angle'])
                y1 = line['y'] + line['timer'] // 5 * sin(line['angle'])
                x2 = other_line['x'] + other_line['timer'] // 5 * cos(other_line['angle'])
                y2 = other_line['y'] + other_line['timer'] // 5 * sin(other_line['angle'])
                if dist((line['x'], line['y']), (other_line['x'], other_line['y'])) < 50:
                    l(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (line['x'], line['y']), (other_line['x'], other_line['y']), 1)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (line['x'], line['y']), 2)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (other_line['x'], other_line['y']), 2)
                if dist((line['x'], line['y']), (x2, y2)) < 50:
                    l(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (line['x'], line['y']), (x2, y2), 1)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (line['x'], line['y']), 2)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (x2, y2), 2)
                if dist((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) < 50:
                    l(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 1)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (x1, y1), 2)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (x2, y2), 2)
                if dist((x1, y1), (other_line['x'], other_line['y'])) < 50:
                    l(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (x1, y1), (other_line['x'], other_line['y']), 1)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (x1, y1), 2)
                    circle(screen, (alpha, alpha, alpha), (other_line['x'], other_line['y']), 2)
        line['x'] += cos(line['angle'])
        line['y'] += sin(line['angle'])
        if line['x'] < 0 or line['x'] > width or line['y'] < 0 or line['y'] > height:
            lines.remove(line)
            continue
        if line['timer'] > 500:
            line['fade-out'] = True
        if line['fade-out']:
            line['timer'] -= 1
        else:
            line['timer'] += 1
        mouse_x, mouse_y = get_pos()
        if dist((line['x'], line['y']), (mouse_x, mouse_y)) < 100:
            if temp > 50:
                lines.remove(line)
            else:
                temp += 1
            line['fade-out'] = False
            angle_to_mouse = atan2(mouse_y - line['y'], mouse_x - line['x'])
            line['x'] += cos(angle_to_mouse) * 5
            line['y'] += sin(angle_to_mouse) * 5
    flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```